# Link html descarga PDF ¿Cómo hacerlo a una nueva ventana?

Tags: html, pdf, enlace

```
<a href="/files/normas/home.PDF" target="_blank">Versión editable con horario de lunes a sábado</a>
```

Utilizando `target="_blank"` no me funcionó, aún así no me respeta la apertura en una nueva venta, en cuanto presiono procede a la descarga.
Alguien sabe qué está ocurriendo, cabe decir que he usado `window.open()` de javascript y aun así no, incluso `target="pdf-frame"` y nada. **Solucion?**

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con javascript:

```
<a onclick="openInNewTab('files/normas/home.PDF');">Versión editable con horario de lunes a sábado</a>

<script>
function openInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
</script>
```

Observación: Elimina el `/` antes de la carpeta `files`

Comment: no work señor! :/

Comment: Qué es exactamente lo que sucede? Te abre en nueva ventana, descarga y cierra inmediatamente? Te abre nueva ventana con mensaje de error? Nunca abre al darle clic?

Comment: de echo solo es con un archivo en PDF que hace eso, los demas si puedo abrirlos sin problema, _abre la pestaña y la cierra descargando el archivo_